# How to get the promptValue of AlertIOS.prompt

Tags: ios, react-native

I dont understand how the promptValue is stored.
I have the following function and I want to pass the promptValue to the callback function "this.rename". I dont know how to get this value. The example published by the react native people is doing some mysterious stuff to get this value. Can anyone explain?

```
renamePrompt: function(line) {
    AlertIOS.prompt(
        'Rename',
        line.name,
        this.rename
    );
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AlertIOS.prompt` accepts a couple of parameters. Let's take a look at them:

```
AlertIOS.prompt(
'Title', 'Default Value', 
[{text: 'Button One', onPress: this.firstButtonPress.bind(this)}, 
{text: 'Button Two', onPress: this.secondButtonPress.bind(this)}]
)
```

The first parameter that `AlertIOS.prompt` accepts is the `title` -- what gets displayed to the user. It's a required `propType`.

The next parameter is a `value`, which is what gets pre-filled into the text box for your user. This is an *optional* `propType`.

After that, the array you see maps to the buttons that your user gets to tap on. These buttons are represented as objects, with some key/value pairs. The first is `text`, which will display the button text. The second is `onPress`, which is a method that you specify to handle that specific button being pressed.

In order to retrieve the value of the button, you need to bind `this` (in this case, it's the prompt) to your `onPress` method. If you do this, you can have your `onPress` handler access the typed in value as such:

```
firstButtonPress(value) {
  console.log(value)
}
```

This button array is *conditionally optional*. If you choose not to give a list of buttons, AlertIOS will expect you to pass in a callback function as a parameter for `AlertIOS.prompt` (but not both a set of buttons and a callback).